# Android slider library crashes when including into my app?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to include this [Slider library](https://github.com/wunderlist/android-sliding-layer-lib) into my code.

When I added this to my layout:

> ```
> <SlidingLayer
>     android:id="@+id/slidingLayer1"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="@dimen/layer_height"
>     android:elevation="2dip"
>     android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
>     android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
>
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:background="@color/primary_light">
>
>         <WebView
>             android:id="@+id/authWebView"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:drawablePadding="15dip"
>             android:paddingBottom="80dp"
>             android:textSize="17sp"
>             android:textColor="@color/primary_text"/>
>
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/buttonClose"
>             style="@style/ButtonRed"
>             android:onClick="buttonClicked"
>             android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
>             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>             android:text="@string/close_button_container"/>
>     </RelativeLayout>
> </SlidingLayer>
> ```

and including the

```
private SlidingLayer mSlidingLayer;
```

then, in onCreate():

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
initSlider();
```

and further in the initSlider() method:

```
private void initSlider() {
    mSlidingLayer = (SlidingLayer) findViewById(R.id.slidingLayer1);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    setupSlidingLayerPosition(prefs.getString("layer_location", "bottom"));
    setupSlidingLayerTransform(prefs.getString("layer_transform", "none"));
    setupShadow(prefs.getBoolean("layer_has_shadow", false));
    setupLayerOffset(prefs.getBoolean("layer_has_offset", false));
    setupPreviewMode(prefs.getBoolean("preview_mode_enabled", false));
}
```

whereas the setup* method within the initSlider() was taken from [here](https://github.com/wunderlist/android-sliding-layer-lib/blob/master/SlidingLayerSample/src/main/java/com/slidinglayersample/MainActivity.java).

But my app crashes at setcontentview in the onCreate() with this error message:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.mysliderapp, PID:
>   22831 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mysliderapp/com.mysliderapp.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error
>   inflating class SlidingLayer  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46:
>   Error inflating class SlidingLayer    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:319)
>     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1973)  at
>   com.mysliderapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:99)   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255) 
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142) 
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203) 
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)      at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.view.SlidingLayer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.mysliderapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mysliderapp-2,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]    at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)      at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)      at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)      at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:319) 
>     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1973)      at
>   com.mysliderapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:99)   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169) 
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255) 
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142) 
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203) 
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)      at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `SlidingLayer` to `com.wunderlist.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer` in your XML layout.

When using external compontents, Android Studio usually get problems while inflating component only by name, so you need to give full package name.

```
<com.wunderlist.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer
    android:id="@+id/slidingLayer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/layer_height"
    android:elevation="2dip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/primary_light">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/authWebView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:drawablePadding="15dip"
            android:paddingBottom="80dp"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonClose"
            style="@style/ButtonRed"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/close_button_container"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.wunderlist.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course that won't work.Logcat says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.SlidingLayer"
```

These things are normal or something like general skills and returns your search or skills about it.Also, you could check that library's sample too:

```
<com.wunderlist.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer
    xmlns:slidingLayer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/slidingLayer1"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/layer_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/layer_height"
    slidingLayer:shadowDrawable="@drawable/sidebar_shadow"
    slidingLayer:shadowSize="@dimen/shadow_size"
    slidingLayer:offsetDistance="@dimen/offset_distance"
    slidingLayer:previewOffsetDistance="@dimen/preview_offset_distance"
    slidingLayer:stickTo="top|bottom|right|left"
    slidingLayer:changeStateOnTap="true">

    …
    …
</com.wunderlist.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer>
```